# cordova build for windows 8 opened deviceready page and closes immediately

Tags: cordova, windows-8

I have a `cordova` project its already working with `android`,but when i tried to run it for `windows8` its opening only the `deviceready` page and closes immediately.

I am using the below commands on CLI

```
cordova platfrom add windows
cordova build windows8
cordova emulate windows8
```

**Note:** I have installed `Node.js`.and latest version of `cordova`

Comment: I find the similar problem when my app use, in javascript, some unexpected code ( android webview and windows 8 use different engine, for this reason in android worked well ), if you try to inspect the javascript you can find a more specific error in the console. You can use the console in visual studio or weinre if you prefer a webkit like tool.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the the hint now i am able to overcome that device ready screen,now getting a different error MakeAppx.exe exited with code 1

Comment: Ok this error is raised when the application stop with error, but non talk about the error, there are some other usefull thing in log above this error?
If not try to use [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) to inspect the console and search if there some problems in the WebView context.